# gtkplugin.h: no such file or directory [centos 8]?

Tags: plugins, makefile, gtk, centos8

Fatal error: gtkplugin.h: no such file or directory
I am trying to use make to install plugin for pidgin on centos 8 we have seen the above error.

Even after installing gtk,gtk2/3 devel packages we couldn't get the headfile.

Comment: `gtkplugin.h` is provided by the CentOS 8 package `pidgin-devel` .............. See answer by  Prasad Bonthu about enabling the "powertools" repo. ...... INFO, search a file : `dnf provides */gtkplugin.h` ....... `dnf install pidgin-devel`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with centos 8 distribution since there is no pidgin-devel package by default yum installation. So with the use of dnf command and enabling powertools we can install it by using the below command:

```
 dnf --enablerepo=powertools install pidgin-devel
```

[Please refer the link](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/pidgin-devel-2.13.0-5.el8.x86_64.rpm.html)